# Remove link text on div collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This below code is used for hide and unhide a div but how can we remove the link text "Search" on click and display a minu - sign instead?

```
<div class="expandContent"><a href="#" title="Click here to search."> &nbsp; &nbsp; 
    <i class='icon-search' title='Click here to search.'></i> SEARCH </a>
</div>
<div class="showMe" style="display:none">

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.expandContent').click(function(){
        $('.showMe').slideToggle('slow');
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change html inside the `a` tag using jquery

```
      <div class="expandContent" id="expandContent">
  <a href="#" title="Click here to search.">
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <i class="icon-search" title="Click here to search."></i>
    <span id="toggleText">SEARCH</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".expandContent").click(function() {
      $(".showMe").slideToggle("slow");
      if ($("#toggleText").text() === "SEARCH") {
        $(".expandContent a").html(` &nbsp; &nbsp;
<i class="icon-search" title="Click here to search."></i><span id="toggleText">&#45;</span>`);
      } else {
        $(".expandContent a").html(` &nbsp; &nbsp;
<i class="icon-search" title="Click here to search."></i><span id="toggleText">SEARCH</span>`);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: but upon clicking the - the text wont come back?

Comment: I'd suggest 'toggling' between `-` and `SEARCH`

Comment: @AbdullahAbid how when uncollapse its the text is search but when open hide search and when click hide search then search text display?

Comment: i'm not quite sure what you asked in the above question but when you click `div` the text of `span` is checked and if it is `SEARCH` the inner html of the `a` is changed and unicode of Hyphen/Minus i.e `&#45` is displayed and when the text of the span is not `SEARCH` a span with text `SEARCH` is displayed

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly it appears you want to toggle the search results using a icon. I used a similar approach using a `<button>` element (instead of the anchor element).

The `+` and `-` inside the button element is switched using jQuery's `text()` along with a [conditional ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
$('.btn-search').click(function() {
  $(this).text() === '+' ?  $(this).text('-') : $(this).text('+');
  $('.showMe').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```css
.showMe {
  border: 2px solid crimson;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-search">+</button>

<div class="showMe" style="display:none">
  <p>Search results go here...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to show/hide an element, but using CSS approach which is exactly faster than javascript. You can set content value whatever you wish from [UNICODE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/)

```js
$('.expandContent').click(function(){
        $('.showMe').slideToggle('slow');
        $(this).toggleClass('collapsed');
    });
```

```css
.showMe {
   display:none;
}
.expandContent {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.expandContent:before {
    content: '\1f50d SEARCH';
}
.expandContent.collapsed:before {
    content: '\2192';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="expandContent" title="Click here to search."></div>
<div class="showMe">showMe</div>
```